# Node Wrangler - No folder selected

Tags: node-editor

I'm new to this forum and to Blender as well. I'm starting to learn a little bit of Blender 2.8 and just tried to use the Node Wrangler add-on. I when try to click the 'Add Principled Setup' option on the Shader Editor I just have a `No Folder Selected' response. What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This might be a bug, it seems to work fine in v2.81 which was released last week.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I thinks it's as simple as you first have to click on the "principled BSDF" otherwise blender doesn't know where you want to add the principled set-up.

So just click on the node to make sure it's highlighted and try again!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately I already tried to select 'Principle BSDF', 'Material Output' or both, without a different response in any case. I just tried again and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Deselect every node first by clicking on an empty space in the grid, then click the Principled BSDF, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard.